# Two Object with Same Schema - Effects of Actions on each other

Tags: xml, schema, object

I am asking this question for the curiosity ?

I came across following Interview Question asked to someone -

Q: "I have two identical objects with same schema. If I want any action performed on any field of one object like deletion of field will also delete same field on other object. How can I achieve this ?"

**Answers :** (Are they correct ??)

> 1) Not possible

--> Great, problem solved (not really, but end of discussion here.)

> 2) Possible , using Schema Builder (Something doing with XML,etc.)

--> well then 
 I have confusion

Deleting field -deletes xml for that field-for that object.
 --- but how can - it will delete field from another object (even it shares same schema)

1) XML in object "FirstObject

```
<fields>
<fullName>MyField__c</fullName>
<defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
<externalId>false</externalId>
<label>My Field </label>
<trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
<trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
<type>Checkbox</type>
</fields>
```

2) XML in object "SecondObject

```
<fields>
<fullName>MyField__c</fullName>
<defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
<externalId>false</externalId>
<label>My Field</label>
<trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
<trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
<type>Checkbox</type>
</fields>
```

Lets say XML matches for both fields - but they belongs to two different objects.

How/ Why Salesforce delete field from secondObject ?

and what if I dont want to ?

**AND** 
**If both the answers are wrong ! Then what will be the answer for this question ?**

Comment: You cannot have two identical objects with the exact same schema as the NAME xml would be different at least. Also the XML would have to include the object xml as well so it knows which field it it supposed to delete. You can;t just send the field xml and expect it to delete all fields matching that name. Taken literally the question is not even possible.

Comment: What if I have to do that ? (XML-is just given to show same fields are there, lets not consider XML). 
 Can I write some trigger to do so ? or Can I do it in any way ?

Comment: Its not possible as the premise of the question is not correct. You cannot have two identical objects in the first places and thus cannot have two identical schemas